# Simple batch script starting adb not working on Windows

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, cmd, adb

I would like to simply start adb with following script commands.
I am not able to do. Can someone help?

```
set adbstart = C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb
%adbstart%
```

output is:

```
set adbstart = C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb
```

that's all. I expected the help page from adb.

Answer (score 0):

How stupid this is !

removing the spaces in assigning solved the issue. really stupid !

```
set adbstart=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb
call %adbstart%
```